# WEBP resample lost transparency

Tags: php, gd, webp

If I resample transparent WEBP image, the background color black. The metodes, helped me for PNG, not works with WEBP.

example:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecolortransparent($thumb, imagecolorallocate($thumb, 0, 0, 0));
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are on an old version of Gd? It seems old versions of Gd discards the alpha channel when saving webp. More on that problem here: https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert/issues/238#issuecomment-545928597

Proposed solutions:

- Upgrade Gd
- Tell your users to upgrade Gd
- Use another tool, such as Imagick or Vips

Can you reveal your version of Gd and PHP?